# Establishing a connection between R and a Hive (Hadoop) database

Tags: r, jdbc, hadoop, hive

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

I am assuming that RJDBC would help; but from my (likely naive) understanding, a bit of tweaking is necessary to write or adapt a Hive driver for this.

Relevant documentation:

- http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hive/HiveClient
- http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJDBC/RJDBC.pdf

Any help or suggestion is welcome! If no one did this before, I would be happy to code a bit towards a solution but I know next to no Java.

Answer (score 2):

R can be interfaced with Hive via RJDBC. However, you'll need a Hive server and drivers.

Hive server:

```
hive --service hiveserver 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null &
```

Drivers: download Toad for Cloud DBs, http://www.toadworld.com/m/freeware/566.aspx, and use drivers included there (unzip the jars and look for the files below).

Below is an R function that you can define to create a connection to a Hive server.

```
hive_connection <- function(   hostname= 'dlhive01.cloud.msrch', port= 10000, lib_dir ){
  library( RJDBC )

  hive_jars <- c('commons-logging-1.0.4.jar','hadoop-core-0.20.2+737.jar',    'hive-exec-0.7.1-cdh3u1.jar', 'hive-jdbc-0.7.1-cdh3u1.jar',    'hive-metastore-0.7.1-cdh3u1.jar', 'hive-service-0.7.1-cdh3u1.jar', 'libfb303.jar','libthrift.jar', 'log4j-1.2.15.jar', 'slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar', 'slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar' )

  # lib_dir: directory containing the jars above.
  hive_class_path <- sprintf( '%s/%s', lib_dir, hive_jars )

  drv <- JDBC( 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver',   classPath=  hive_class_path, "`" )

  server <- sprintf( 'jdbc:hive://%s:%s/default', hostname, port )

  return ( dbConnect( drv, server ) )
}
```

Comment: When following this advice perhaps one should be mindful of versions.  AFAIK, the hadoop-core-*.jar files are not present in the 2.4 version of hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested these, but try the [RHIPE](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~sguha/rhipe/) and [hive](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=409) packages.

See [this quora question](http://www.quora.com/How-can-R-and-Hadoop-be-used-together) (particularly Jeff Hammerbacher's answer) for a discussion of other options.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but -- as far as I can tell none of these allow me to query a hive database. The hive package, in particular, seems to me to have nothing to do with Hive!